# Trouble Cloning Hard Drive with Clonezilla

Tags: clonezilla, disk-cloning

I'm trying to transfer a 2TB drive to a 4TB drive with Clonezilla. The problem is that the transfer speeds are progressively slowing down.

Initially the status bar said that the clone would finish in around 4 hours and the transfer speeds are over 9GB per minute. Within minutes the speed started dropping to 8GB to 7GB, and the time getting proportionally longer. Around four hours later, at around 1.35 percent completed, the transfer speed was around 135MB per minute and dropping. The estimated time was around 198 hours till completion. At that time I stopped it. I did this twice with similar result. Once with Clonezilla loaded on the target drive, and once on a USB drive.

I don't believe that the physical hard drives are slowing down. Because I transferred the information with a Windows utility, but then formatted because I realized Windows didn't transfer over.

Thank you if anyone can help.

Comment: What your precise question is exactly is not clear.  You don't indicate how the drives are even connect to the PC.

Comment: imaging a 2TB mechanical disk should take in excess of 8 hours just on the read end, and max transfer speed for a USB2 disk is about 30MB/s. so for a 2TB volume, that would be about 18 hours.

Comment: The drives are being transferred with sata 6Gb/s.

Comment: First no hard drive utilizes all the bandwidth on 6g, maybe 100mb/s averages as the information is recorded in smaller and smaller circles as you approach the center of the drive.  Second, bad/weak sectors can dramatically reduce data transfer.  If the hard drive is doing a lot of error correcting it will really slow down.  You would have to test with spinrite(grc.com) or mhdd (hddguru.com%2Fsoftware%2F2005.10.02-MHDD%2F) to find out.

Comment: When I used the utility it maintained a consistent speed.

Comment: @yak27, if it did, then it was lying to you. Mechanical disks don't work that way. Last time I used ddrescue, I noticed that the speed jumped between 30MB/s and 90MB/s, but the amazing thing was, that after just a minute, it had established a 45MB/s average, and even with all the alterations minute by minute, that average did not change by more than 1MB/s over the course of the 46 hour session.

Comment: I used Task Manager to check the speed. What I meant was it maintained a consistent average speed. It was around 135 MB/s - 155 MB/s.